# Is AppII built upon private or public blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

As I was reading about blockchain application, I came across [APPII](https://appii.io/about/), an online verification, career management, and recruitment platform.

Just wanted to know if is it possible to build an Dapps like this in Hyperledger Composer.
Is it(Appii) a private or a public blockchain network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in regard to Hyperledger Composer yes, its possible, as it sits atop Hyperledger Fabric as its incumbent blockchain where the ledger sits and as you know Fabric is a permissioned blockchain platform.

There is an example here -> http://www.goverticalworkshop.com/resources/how-to-create-a-decentralized-application-running-on-hyperledger-fabric-network

(it has sample links to resources it uses but I do notice that some commands (eg `composer network deploy` need updating, but can see similar from the [docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials)

Sorry you'll have to ask APPII if they're using private or public blockchain or do your own research. Given that they are partnering organisations as verifying institutions/partners and interacting with joe public to upload their CV, so that its constituent claims/artifacts can be validated/verified - the use case is hybrid (it would seem).